# How do I define a specific bean with a qualifier that would designate a specific bean for its dependancies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First thanks for taking the time help. You are all Awesome!

My question:
Say i have some nested properties in my application.yml

```
regions:
 region1:
  delayTime: 10
  threads: 2
 region2:
  delayTime: 5
  threads: 1
```

and a respective component with a config for the regions

```
@Component
public class Region{
   public int delayTime;
   public int threads;
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class RegionConfig{
   @Bean("region1props")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="regions.region1")
   public Region getRegion1(){
        returns new Region();
    }

   @Bean("region2props")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="regions.region2")
   public Region getRegion2(){
        returns new Region();
    }

}
```

If say I also had a `RegionHandler` Component  that had `Region` as a dependency:

```
@Component
public class RegionHandler{
 @AutoWired 
 Region region;
}
```

**ULTIMATELY** i want a `RegionOnePublisher` and `RegionTwoPublisher` Component with no config:

```
@Component
public class RegionOnePublisher{
  @Autowired
   RegionHandler regionOne;// <-- need to configure Region depenandcy as "region1props" bean 
}
//----------------------------------------------
@Component
public class RegionTwoPublisher{
  @Autowired
   RegionHandler regionTwo; // <-- need to configure Region depenandcy as "region2props" bean
}
```

How would I go about defining the config class for `RegionHandler` object such that `@Bean("region1props")` is the `Region` bean dependancy  injected for a `RegionHandler regionOne` and `@Bean("region2props")` as the `Region` bean dependancy  for `RegionHandler regionTwo`?

What I have: [Edited]

```
@Component
public class RegionOnePublisher{
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("regionOneProps")
   RegionHandler regionOne;// <-- need to configure Region depenandcy as "region1props" bean 
}
//----------------------------------------------
@Component
public class RegionTwoPublisher{
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("regionTwoProps")
   RegionHandler regionTwo; // <-- need to configure Region depenandcy as "region2props" bean
} 
}
```

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Constructor injection on `RegionHandler` and not annotate that class with `@Component`, it should help you to use specific `Region` for creating the bean.

```java
public class RegionHandler {

    Region region;

    public RegionHandler(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
}
```

Now your handlers can be registered as beans by changing your config file a bit

```java
@Configuration
public class RegionHandlerConfig{

    @Bean("regionHandler1")
    public RegionHandler getRegionHandlerOne(@Qualifier("region1props") Region region) {
        return new RegionHandler(region);
    }

    @Bean("regionHandler2")
    public RegionHandler getRegionHandlerTwo(@Qualifier("region2props") Region region) {
        return new RegionHandler(region);
    }
}
```

I haven't compiled and checked but this is the basic idea.

Also, do look into whether this pattern would be extendable. I am guessing you have specific logic in the handler and publisher for each region. But I wonder how you would be able to extend it if you have to add more regions. A better structure might be to take a map of the regions from the config and have only one bean of handler and publisher each.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had wanted to do that but this a part of the a bigger project the dev kind of left me high and dry. A ton of code coverage, basically he structured it in a way that RegionHandler cant be configurable but have a specific bean injected into the Publisher. I just edited the last code block

Comment: So what I have understood from your comment is that you cannot update the RegionHandler code at all but still need the publishers to be separate for each Region. And you want to decide the field dependency of RegionHandler from the RegionPublisher.
You could use Reflection to modify the dependency of RegionHandler from RegionPublisher but I would suggest against that. Considering the RegionHandler is already in the spring context, any changes you make will be across the project.
If you want you can create a new instance of RegionHandler in each RegionPublisher and then use Reflection.